# No se puede iniciar el servidor web de IIS Express al ejecutar un proyecto asp.net en Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, localhost, visual-studio-2019, iis-express

Ayer salió un mensaje en mi laptop, indicando que se actualizarían algunos controladores de windows, le di aceptar y se reinició, después de la actualización, ninguno de mis proyectos asp.net codificados en Visual Studio 2019 podían ejecutarse.
Intenté eliminar la carpeta vs oculta y sigue el error. También eliminé applicationhost del proyecto y nada. He creado nuevos proyectos asp.net y el error continúa, no entiendo realmente que cambió en esa actualización de windows que terminó afectando a mis proyectos asp.net realizados en visual, también tengo proyectos C# de escritorio, esos si están corriendo normal.
Dejo capturas del error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Desinstalé IIS Express y volví a instalarlo y todos mis proyectos asp.net volvieron a ejecutarse con normalidad.